# Python *args returns tuple rather than pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, args

Have a function that returns a series of dataframes.

```
def frames():
  bla bla
  return df1, df2, df3, df4
```

I would like to write a function that will append these frames together *without my having to list the count* so that I can have more or fewer frames in future

```
def appender(*args):
   condition goes here
       append things that are true
```

I'd like to be able to call it such that

```
appender(frames())
```

will return a full frame of frames that passed the condition.

Right now the frames() function returns a tuple of four frames. Is there any easy fix to unpack the tuple?

Thanks for any help!

Clem

**UPDATE Here's an example**

```
def frames():

    df1 = pd.DataFrame()

    df2 = pd.DataFrame()

    df3 = pd.DataFrame(['not', 'empty'])

    df4 = pd.DataFrame(['not', 'empty'])

    return df1, df2, df3, df4

def appender(*args):
    main_frame = pd.DataFrame()
    for arg in args:
        if arg.empty != True:
            assignment_frame = assignment_frame.append(arg)

    return assignment_frame


appender(frames())
```

gives

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 appender(frames())

in appender(*args)
      2     main_frame = pd.DataFrame()
      3     for arg in args:
----> 4         if arg.empty != True:
      5             assignment_frame = assignment_frame.append(arg)
      6

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'empty'

Comment: You should probably include sample data and expected output. Also, your condition needs greater detail.

Comment: Maybe something like `pd.concat([df for cond, df in zip(conditions, frames()) if cond])`.  Someone will give you more concrete code if you can provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: how about just call pd.concat(args) in appender?

Comment: I agree, we should have some sample data to play with. We can't answer because there are things that could greatly impact the answer (for example, are the columns the same for the data frames?). Here's a simple way to create a sample data frame: pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code would kind-of work if you called it via `appender(*frames())`, but you would still get an error because `assignment_frame` should be `main_frame`.

However, there is even a simpler approach.  Just pass a collection of dataframes and use a list comprehension with your condition to filter them.

Note that YOU DO NOT WANT TO BUILD DATAFRAMES BY APPENDING!  This is called quadratic copy, because each time you call `append` a copy of the original dataframe is returned plus the newly appended dataframe.  This will get *very slow*.  See timings below.

```
def appender(dataframes):
    return pd.concat([df for df in dataframes if not df.empty])  # Optional: .reset_index()


>>> appender(frames())
       0
0    not
1  empty
0    not
1  empty
```

**Timings (concat vs append)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))

%timeit df2 = pd.concat([df] * 1000)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 54.7 ms per loop

%%timeit
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for _ in range(1000):
    df3 = df3.append(df)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.28 s per loop

>>> df3.equals(df2)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors:

1. Remember to unpack in your initial function arguments.
2. Your variable name for the dataframe in `appender` changes, keep it consistent.

Here's a working example:

```
def appender(*args):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for arg in args:
        if arg.empty != True:
            df = df.append(arg)
    return df

appender(*frames())
```

But [`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) in a loop is inefficient due to unnecessary data copying; it's not recommended. A more efficient way of writing this is possible via [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and a list comprehension:

```
def appender(*dfs):
    return pd.concat([df for df in dfs if not df.empty], ignore_index=True)
```

Using `ignore_index=True` ensures your output dataframe has the default `pd.RangeIndex` index.